# How to get current content item is using custom field inherit from Sitecore.Shell.Applications.ContentEditor.Text

Tags: custom-field

I created an customfield, the class implemented like below:

```
public class GoogleMapField :Sitecore.Shell.Applications.ContentEditor.Text, IContentField
{}
```

In this class I want to get current content itemID is using this customField in ContentEditor.
I tried to use ItemID property but It's not success

```
public string ItemID { get; set; }
```

Comment: Do you mean you want page item id where form has applied?

Comment: I mean. I have a item use that custom field. Then I want to get that item id in the code that implement my custom field.

Comment: Take a look at Rich's answer here, it may help: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32498571/how-to-get-all-pagetemplate-that-contains-a-specific-component

Comment: @Hugo that post is nothing to do with custom content editor fields, that's for ContentSearch fields in an index

Answer (score 1):

This has always been an issue.  Using GetItem(), just returns the Content Editor Item in the core Db.  What I ended up doing was a bit of a kludge but it works.
In my Render method I did this:

```
var id = !string.IsNullOrEmpty(ItemID)
                        ? ItemID
                        : ControlAttributes.Substring(ControlAttributes.IndexOf("//master/", StringComparison.Ordinal) + 9,
                            38);
   var item = new ID(id).ToSitecoreItem(db);
```